# Angular deployment on Gitlab CI not working properly

Tags: angular, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci, angular9

I'm developing a webpage on Angular 9.1.9 and deploying on [Gitlab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/).
I've managed to deploy it but the Angular Build seems not to show on [the page](https://neural-fuse.gitlab.io/neural-fuse/) but the **build code** is uploaded.

We just gave up and deployed it on `netlify`, and it works, but we want to learn to make it work on Gitlab

Here is the repository with all the code: https://gitlab.com/neural-fuse/neural-fuse/-/tree/develop

[Here](https://gitlab.com/neural-fuse/neural-fuse/-/jobs/675896052) is the deployment and the Angular Build (in the browse button);
and the **.gitlab-ci.yml** code:

```yaml
image: node:13.0.1 

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.9
    - npm install
    - ng build --prod
    - mkdir public
    - mv dist/neural-fuse/* public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public

  only:
  - develop
```

Comment: I might just not be getting how Angular Builds work. Or gitlab artifacts

Comment: I cloned your project and launched it on local machine. It was working well. But when I checked browser console of your [page](https://neural-fuse.gitlab.io/neural-fuse/), I saw some error which may have been the cause of page loading failure. But since you mentioned that deployment on **Netlify** was successful, there may be a problem with **GitLab Pages**. I found some issues: [1](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/-/issues/244) and [2](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/hosting-my-static-angular-site-on-gitlab-pages-isnt-working/39136)

Comment: @AmirMohammadDadkhah I didn't thing about checking the console errors on the website , I'll be checking that links, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you missed here is
`- ng build --prod --base-href /neural-fuse/` instead of `- ng build --prod`

In gitlab, your project goes to gitlab pages on `yourusername.gitlab.io/yourprojectname/`. Angular expects to be deployed (learn more in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)) at root level (i.e. without the `'yourprojectname/'` at the back). So we need to set it to work on `'yourprojectname/'` base.

Finally, keeping the `node` version, the `@angular/cli` version and the branch you stated in the OP, the `yml` should look like this:

```yml
image: node:13.0.1 

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.9
    - npm install
    - ng build --prod --base-href /neural-fuse/
    - mkdir public
    - mv dist/neural-fuse/* public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public

  only:
  - develop
```

Comment: How does GitLab know the command 'ng'? All attempts that I have tried for the past 2 days it will not execute and I am using exactly what you have posted up to the 'ng build ...'

Comment: @edjm it is suposed to work because you installed angular cli before. It's a problem I've not tried to solve this problem. I only know how to deploy plain html at the moment.